# setText() doesn't really work Python

Tags: python, input, label, pyqt4, settext

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui
from Windows.intro_win import Ui_Introduction
from Windows.post_adder_win import Ui_postTool
import win32clipboard
import pyHook

class Intro(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Introduction()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
class postTool(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui2 = Ui_postTool()
        self.ui2.setupUi(self)
    def setModPosition(self):
        self.ui2.lineEdit_2.setText("something")
        print "nomnom"


def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    KeyClicked = event.KeyID
    if KeyClicked == 121:
        print "Debug from keyboardEvent"
        OMD_post.show()
        postTool().setModPosition()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    OMD_intro = Intro()
    OMD_post = postTool()
    OMD_intro.show()
    eventkey = pyHook.HookManager()
    eventkey.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
    eventkey.HookKeyboard()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It doesn't really work - text didn't change - why it doesn't work? It doesn't give me any error (but print prints what it should)
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21125662/compilation/_00398.jpg

Comment: it doesn't look like you're calling `setModPosition()`

Comment: Yeah i do through onkeyboardevent, it prints debug "nomnom", i forget to mention.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see that. Have you checked if any of the other slots work, such as `setMaxLength()`, or `selectAll()`?

Comment: I don't use any other slots for this input, here is my code if needed https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21125662/compilation/post_adder_win.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postTool().setModPosition()` in `OnKeyboardEvent` changes the text in the lineEdit of a **newly created** postTool, which you won't see since you don't `show()` the new widget. What you probably want to do is to call `setText` on `OMD_post`.

Try replacing the `OnKeyBoardEvent` module level function with  a [keyPressEvent](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent) function in the `postTool`, or maybe use a QShortCut.

```
class postTool(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui2 = Ui_postTool()
        self.ui2.setupUi(self)
    def setModPosition(self):
        self.ui2.lineEdit_2.setText("something")
        print "nomnom"
    def keyPressEvent(event):
        if type(event) == QtGui.QKeyEvent:
            key = str(event.text()).lower()
            if key == 'whatever':
                self.setModPosition()
```

Alternatively,

```
class postTool(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        ... # the existing stuff
        QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("F10"), self, self.setModPosition)
```

Comment: The problem is when I use QT key event, It doesn't work when window is not selected (I mean if I use key in other program), the widget is showed when I click F10 (aka keyboardevent), then it calls changing text inside of postTool()

Comment: @Marcin: Right. Have you tried just changing `postTool().setModPosition()` to `OMD_post.setModPosition()`? It looks to me like `OMD_post` shouldn't be in the scope of of `OnKeyBoardEvent`, but since you're already using `OMD_post` in the line above..

Comment: /me stupid, /me stupid (about 9000 times later of being stupid), it works after changing to OMD_post THANKS, but i don't really know WHY it wasn't working when i didn't use OMD_post (it was calling method from postToool [debug was working] )